# Uncaught (in promise), Can't read configurator when opening new angular project

Tags: angular-cli

I'm trying to create a new angular project.

I did `ng new routing-app --routing --defaults` to create the project. It didn't ask for css/sass/... such as before. I can run the project with `ng serve`.

When I open my website (without creating something), I get this error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurator')
    at testerMaker.js:1
    at c (testerMaker.js:1)
    at Generator._invoke (testerMaker.js:1)
    at Generator.next (testerMaker.js:1)
    at w (testerMaker.js:1)
    at r (testerMaker.js:1)
```

So I can fix it by myself because it's from an unknow ts file.

The issue is that routing failed. It always show main page only

`ng version` output:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.9
Node: 12.16.1
Package Manager: npm 8.0.0

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.9
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.9
@schematics/angular             12.2.9
ng-packagr                      12.2.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I report this in [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21922).

They suggested to check in incognito mode : No error.

I check which extension was creating this issue, and on which site.

I found that `wanteeed` create the issue everywhere (just, for other website I didn't see it). So, to fix this issue, I just remove the extension.